# Hibernate reverse engineering with sybase

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement Hibernate reverse engineering with sybase database, but I keep getting the below error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The 'CREATE TABLE' command is not allowed within a multi-statement transaction in the 'tempdb' database.
```

I see that it's executing the below procedure on my database

```
devConfig..sp_jdbc_primarykey 'devConfig','dbo','Customer'
```

This command runs fine if I execute this from any DB tool like (squirrel or DBArtisan) but fails via hibernate.

I was thinking if I can disable the Hibernate transactions somehow, but I don't find any such way.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Is hibernate running in chained transaction mode (eg, autocommit=false)? and if so, can you disable it (eg, autocommit=true)?